# Why is @AfterReturning only executed after @AfterThrowing on exception?

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

I have the following:

```
@AfterReturning("executionOfTrustedAnnotatedMethod()")
public void afterReturningFromTrustedMethodExecution() { ... }

@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "executionOfTrustedAnnotatedMethod()")
public void afterThrowingByExecutionOfTrustedAnnotatedMethod() { ... }
```

And Im observing this behaviour which does not make sense to me:

- If the method captured by this pointcut does not throw an exception, @AfterReturning is executed
- If the method throws an exception, @AfterReturning is only executed if @AfterThrowing exists and is executed first

What I am trying to accomplish is to run some code at the end of the execution of a method regardless if there was an exception thrown or not. But now this code runs twice (if I have both afterReturning and afterThrowing) or not at all (if I only have afterReturning) if there is an exception thrown.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Piotr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to execute a code after method regardless if there was an exception thrown or not, you need to use `@After` instead.

Comment: Great! Thanks ;) Do you have any idea why I got that odd behavior? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @Piotr: I don't know. Looks strange, indeed.